# Python on Ubuntu 18.04.4: command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu

Ok, let's start by saying that I'm an absolute beginner in programming, and I wanted to start from Python. I've learned the very basics and I read that it's best to create a virtual environment when working on a project. Since I have three Python versions, 2.something, 3.6.9 and 3.8.2, and I wanted to use the latest version, I used the following command:

```
python3.8 -m venv env
```

And it gives me this message, which I don't really understand:

```
Error: Command '['/home/robert/python/python_p/env/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

But the environment is actually created.
Nonteheless, when I try to work in the environment by using

```
source env/bin/activate
```

It gives me this:

```
bash: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

The important thing here is that if I use the

```
python3 -m venv
```

command it works just fine, but it sets the 3.6.9 version by default, which I don't want to use. I know I can change it later, but it has become personal.

Comment: Is that error message the only output produced, or is there more? I suspect the actual error message was before the line you posted.

Comment: I posted the whole thing, no other output has been produced.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the error is due to not having a `python3.8-venv` package installed.

> Error: Command '['/home/robert/python/python_p/env/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

You can try the following

```
$ rm -rf venv
$ apt install python3.8-venv
...
$ python3.8 -m venv venv
... success
```

You may also find [this](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1059) useful

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Loads of questions on this around and many rabbithole answers.

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to add "sudo" to the second command:
sudo apt install python3.8-venv